# Joomla MVC implementation, default triggered functions

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, manual

Is there any place that shows/describes how Joomla MVC implementation goes? I'm trying to undestand it but there are many things that just happen and have no code to start it. I assume joomla run it for me but with no explanation what joomla runs in default I cannot control it:(

After main component file ComponentName.php code goes to main controller: controller.php and then it goes a little fuzzy:(

Any place that describes it?

Answer (score 2):

I think the free version of http://www.component-creator.com/ will be really useful for you to see how MVC works :) Create a component and check the code, remove things, add others and compare the code I think it will help.